# weird Seg fault

Tags: c++, strptime

For some reason, my code is throwing a segfault. I think it has something to do with the actual use of the timeinfo variable, but I am not too sure. I have no idea why not using the variable would throw a seg fault, and using it will not throw a seg fault.

this code will throw a seg fault: https://www.onlinegdb.com/Hk1JT-Ys4

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>    
#include <time.h>   
#include <string.h>   

using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    string timeString = "3019-05-17T22:9:00Z";
    char char_array[timeString.length() + 1]; 
    strcpy(char_array, timeString.c_str()); 
    struct tm * timeinfo;
    strptime(char_array, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", timeinfo);

//  time_t now = time(0);
//  struct tm * gmtNow= gmtime(&now);

//     if(mktime(timeinfo)>mktime(gmtNow))
//         puts("yes");
//     else
//         puts("no");

    char buffer [80];
    strftime (buffer,80,"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", timeinfo);
    puts (buffer);

  return 0;
}
```

this code will not:
https://onlinegdb.com/H10GTZYoV

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>    
#include <time.h>   
#include <string.h>   

using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    string timeString = "3019-05-17T22:9:00Z";
    char char_array[timeString.length() + 1]; 
    strcpy(char_array, timeString.c_str()); 
    struct tm * timeinfo;
    strptime(char_array, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", timeinfo);

    time_t now = time(0);
    struct tm * gmtNow= gmtime(&now);

    if(mktime(timeinfo)>mktime(gmtNow))
        puts("yes");
    else
        puts("no");

    char buffer [80];
    strftime (buffer,80,"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", timeinfo);
    puts (buffer);

  return 0;
}
```

here is another weird case:
https://onlinegdb.com/rkOTCZKs4

Comment: `strptime(char_array, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", timeinfo);` is causing the seg fault

Comment: `char char_array[timeString.length() + 1];` -- Not valid C++.  Arrays in C++ must have their sizes denoted by a compile-time expression, not a runtime-determined value.  Why not simply use `std::string`?

Comment: `strptime(timeString.c_str(), "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", timeinfo);` -- No need for the unnecessary copy, and no need for the non-standard C++ code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
struct tm * timeinfo;
strptime(char_array, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", timeinfo);
```

`timeinfo` is a pointer, but it's uninitialized, resulting in undefined behavior. You're lucky it didn't wipe your hard drive. Instead, it probably just wrote the date to random bytes in memory. If that memory *happens* to be real memory for your app, you'll just get weird bugs. If that memory *happens* to not be memory your app has, the operating system will probably crash your app.

The correct way of doing this would be:

```
struct tm timeinfo;
memset(&timeinfo, 0, sizeof(struct tm));
strptime(char_array, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", &timeinfo);
```

Comment: What do you mean by saying _If that memory is real memory for your app, you'll just get weird bugs_? Could you elucidate it sir? What can be action(s) incurred?

Comment: @snr undefined behaviour is undefined. Anything could happen from the code looking like it works right through to the complete destruction of the entire universe.

Comment: @snr If the memory belongs to your app, one of the possible behaviors, of resulting undefined behavior, is that such memory is overwritten, which would result in you being weirded out, by unrelated variables changing their values, due to such overwriting.